# Why am I getting unexpected input error for this function in R?

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I want the function to return the fahrenheit to celcius equation if I type in for instance, c, 2) and the other way around if I i type in f instead. This is the function I have:

```
Temperatureconverter <- function(v,x){
  x = 0
  if(v == c) {          
    return(x*9/5+32)
  if(v == f){             
    return((x−32)×5/9)
  }}
```

And this is the error:

```
Error in source("~/Documents/MAE4000/R/test.R", echo = TRUE) : 
  ~/Documents/MAE4000/R/test.R:7:14: unexpected input
6:   if(v == f){             
7:     return((x−
                ^
```

Comment: You wrote `return((x−32)×5/9)`      But you should use `*` for multiplication,  not `×`  But based on your error message,  I suspect that your `-`  is not the standard `-`.   I suggest that you delete it and retype.

Comment: ... also: Which looks like a "-" minus sign actually isn't one.

Comment: Also since you are setting x to zero, i.e. a constant, you‘ll always return the same values from your function. In case v==c, it‘s 32, otherwise -160/9, so roughly about -18.

Answer (score 2):

I rewrote the code as below to solve all the missing details:

```
Temperatureconverter <- function(v,x)
{
  if(v == "c") return(x*9/5+32)
  if(v == "f") return((x-32)*5/9)
  else return ("Please enter c for Celsius or f for Fahrenheit")
}

Temperatureconverter("f",100) # calling the function
```

The comments are right:

- Setting x to zero after receiving a value for x made the
  calculation wrong
- The 'minus' was not the proper symbol
- Multiplication should always be *.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I'm new to R, and these small problems are giving me a headache. I really appreciate your help!